# Help identifying UHF RF SMD component

Tags: rf, identification, components

I need some help identifying two components in this RF circuit. I have spent quite a bit of time searching for either, who makes it, or what exactly they do, but no luck. Maybe someone here knows something about them.

The main component in question is the metallic blue package labeled **9413 J7DN**. I am also unable to locate anything on the other two circled components (they are the same, just different markings.) Hopefully figuring out one will aid in narrowing down the others. I am unable to probe anything until an additional power module for the board arrives.

The circuit is the second of four down conversion stages from mm-wave to digital. This 2nd I.F. has two separate signals; both are variable from 2.0 to 2.8GHz using push-push oscillators. The dual-emitter transistors are biased for switching between the two signals.

[image]

Here is a different view - with dimensions on the packages, along with some surrounding components labeled. Measurements were taken via Olympus PRECiV software & an SZX-12.

[image]

Comment: There is a 2.4GHz SAW filter from Epcos called B9413 although the footprint doesn't quite match. Do you know if this pic is from the RX path or TX path? A SAW filter would make perfect sense in the RX path. In which case the cap south of it would be a DC blocking one.

Comment: Also what's the gibberish "SOD 523 SOT 723 SC-79". That's just hogwash... this looks like a SOT23-6 or some other equivalent name. RF antenna switch? There will be resistors in series with one so it matches the layout.

Comment: Yes this is the RX path - the writing on the second part was a few equivalent package sizes that matched. Not the correct ones but simply to give an idea of size. The switching antenna makes sense to be placed after the bandpass filter. I managed to locate the makers of the blue chip; appears to be a custom designed SAW from ACTE. Thanks for your help.